# How to replace a label in a prometheus re-label step?

Tags: prometheus

I'm using the prometheus file based service discovery. However when pulling in my list of servers I realized that my service's metrics endpoint is `/prometheus` no `/metrics`

I've seen that I can use relabelling to fix this.

```
- job_name: 'servers-dev'
  file_sd_configs:
  - files: ['/prometheus/topology.json']

  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [?????]
    action: replace
    target_label: __metrics_path__  #I want this to be /prometheus
    regex: (.+)
```

How can I add in label using relabeling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use relabelling here, you can just add

```
  metrics_path: /prometheus
```

to the scrape config.

To do this with relabelling you'd do:

```
  - target_label: __metrics_path__
    replacement: /prometheus
```

as the defaults are such that you don't need to worry about the other config options.

Comment: :facepalm: Thanks for the reminder of the `metrics_path` I'd been hopping through the Kubernetes SD so much my eyes had crossed.  Also thanks for the relabelling example as I actually needed to add in an extra label and that worked perfectly.